# Last.fm API call from Android application

Tags: java, android, last.fm

I'm trying to make last.fm API call from android application using this package: http://www.u-mass.de/lastfm

From simple java command line program, it works, but not in android application. Using windows and Eclipse

Code itself is very easy:

```
 Artist artist = Artist.getInfo("Depeche Mode", "my_key");
```

I have set internet permission in android manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

After call I end up here, where it prints "caching failed."
http://code.google.com/p/lastfm-java/source/browse/trunk/src/de/umass/lastfm/Caller.java?spec=svn173&r=173

response code there  is -1

```
int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's open-source. Link the source code in Eclipse and go in debug mode.

Comment: Well that's your problem trying to get info on Depeche Mode, no wonder why its crashing...lol

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem.
Its a reported bug.

Solution I found was this :
Just add this line somewhere in your code that will get run prior to calling any of the api methods:
Caller.getInstance().setCache(null);

Note: this will disable Caching..

for more info check this [link](http://code.google.com/p/lastfm-java/issues/detail?id=30)